# Failed to connect to mlab Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to my database on mlab through mongodb.

I have cd to mongodb directory, then I run the code and all I get is this error. If I try to connect over localhost it's fine but on real server I get the error below:

```
./bin/mongo ds151508.mlab.com:51508/dansql -u xx -p xxx

MongoDB shell version v3.6.3  
connecting to: mongodb://ds151508.mlab.com:51508/dansql
2018-02-28T09:31:17.748-0700 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 34.228.213.238:51508, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused  
2018-02-28T09:31:17.749-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server ds151508.mlab.com:51508, connection attempt failed :  
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Could you show your connection to MongoDB line (without your credentials)?

Comment: it's a test db not a production db

Comment: Yet you still need to connect your app to it. For instance if you are using mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: i have done this mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
but when i try to test connection on mongo shell i get the error have mentioned above